# How to implement dynamic WHERE LIKE %A%B%

Tags: c#, linq

I want to implement SQL query like this with Dynamic LINQ

```
SELECT * FROM Product WHERE Name LIKE '%Product%ML%'
```

How can I? (it's not BeginWith, EndWith or Contains)

Comment: [`SqlMethods.Like`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355235.aspx) (i think)

Comment: http://www.simonrhart.com/2008/06/using-like-in-linq-to-sql-under-c.html

Comment: Are you using `linq to sql` or `linq to entities`?

Answer (score 1):

```
LIKE '%A%B%'
```

if i'm not mistaken means "is made up of anything, then A, then anything, then B, then anything": pseudo-coded equivalent logic should be

**edit** turns out it's more complicated than what i thought. *this* should work

```
src.Contains("A") && src.Substring(src.IndexOf("A")+"A".Length).Contains("B")
```